# Test and Production Server

Tags: git

I am using Git for a test and production server and I'm trying to figure out the best way to update the production server.

I have limited SSH access, and don't want to manually update my production server using FTP.

I essentially would like to just be able to run a simple command and have the whole production server files match my dev.

It is also important to note that users will be uploading images, and other files to our production server only, that we can not lose.

Thanks,any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into a deployment tool like [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) or [Fabric](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/22/easy-fabric-deployment-part-1-gitmercurial-and-ssh/). You can set up rules to exclude (or synchronize) certain directories. Alternatively, you could just use [plain git](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/Deploying-websites-with-Git).

Comment: +1 for posting a link with the line, "useful as a chocolate teapot."

I do a similar thing with Subversion, and it really simplifies things.  You can even still have files that are only in the production directory.  As long as they aren't under version control in dev, you shouldn't have a problem.